# JavaScript setInterval, createTextNode, appendChild Doesn't work? Simple?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something which in any other coding language would be quite easy...  I'm trying to add text from an array one character at a time with a small delay between each character being displayed in the browser.  It's a simple script and I'm not getting any errors but I'm not getting any results.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong.  JavaScript is still pretty new to me.  Thanks!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body onload="timedText()">
    <script>
        var arr = ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"];
        var newP = document.createElement("p");

        function timedText() {
            var index = 0;
            while (index < arr.length) { 
                var timerId = setInterval(writeIt(index), 5000);
                index++;
                clearInterval(timerId);
            };
        };

        function writeIt(i) {
            var newT = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
            newP.appendChild(newT);
        };
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You created a `<p>` but never put it in the document. `document.appendChild(newP);`?

Comment: `var timerId = setInterval(writeIt(index), 5000);index++;clearInterval(timerId);` === `writeIt(index); index++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You create a new `<p>` element to hold the letters, but never append that element to the DOM. (You need [`.appendChild(newP)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add it to the `document.body` or to some other existing element.)
- You call `setInterval()`, but then call `clearInterval()` immediately afterwards, before any time has elapsed. So nothing happens. In any case it doesn't make sense to use `setInterval()` from within a loop like that - it would make more sense to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which only schedules a single execution of the function you pass it.
- You are calling the `writeIt()` function *immediately* on each `while` iteration and passing its return value (`undefined`) to `setInterval()`, whereas `setInterval()` expects a function *reference*.

Here is a working version:

```js
var arr = ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"];
var newP = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(newP);

function timedText() {
  var index = 0;
  function nextLetter() {
    newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[index]));
    index++;
    if (index < arr.length) {
      setTimeout(nextLetter, 5000);
    }
  };
  nextLetter();
};

timedText();
```

Notice I don't have a `while` loop in my code. Instead, I'm calling the (nested) function `nextLetter()` to handle whichever letter `index` is up to, then incrementing `index`, then if we haven't yet reached the end of the array I'm using `setTimeout(nextLetter, 5000)` to schedule `nextLetter()` to run again after five seconds. Notice that `nextLetter` does *not* have parentheses after it when passed as a parameter to `setTimeout()` - that's to pass a reference to the function rather than calling the function.

Also I inlined the code from the `writeIt()` function, given that it was really just a one-liner anyway if you omit the temporary variable.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks! I'm still learning JS and it's not like Java, Python, C or other languages.  So, I still have a ways to go.  But this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thumbs Up!

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little confusing at first because you're not just learning the core language itself, you're learning the DOM api methods to interact with elements in the HTML document. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a very handy reference both for the  JS language and for DOM methods provided by the browser.

Comment: @RobG - Good point. I didn't notice that because my demo worked with [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) in the browser I tested in. But I'll edit it to do it with `.appendChild()`.

Comment: Lucky I have a client site where Firefox 38 and IE 10 are the SOE browsers. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add `newP` to `document.body`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body onload="timedText()">
    <script>
        var arr = ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"];
        var newP = document.createElement("p");
        // ADD START
        document.body.appendChild(newP);
        // ADD END

        function timedText() {
            var index = 0;
            while (index < arr.length) { 
                var timerId = setInterval(writeIt(index), 5000);
                index++;
                clearInterval(timerId);
            };
        };

        function writeIt(i) {
            var newT = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
            newP.appendChild(newT);
        };
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: you failed to address the `setInterval` issue :p